# django google_cloud_logging json format

Tags: django, logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to use google_cloud_logging with Django to log JSON logs to Stackdriver. However, the received format on Stackdriver is not as I would expect.

My `settings.py` LOGGING setup looks like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },  
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'INFO',
           'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
    } 
}
```

and I write dictionary logs like: 
`_logger.info({'message_type':'profile', 'runtime': 500})`

I would expect on Stackdriver for messages to appear as:

```
{
    ...
    jsonPayload:{
                  'message_type':'profile',
                  'runtime': 500
                }
 }
```

However they appear with the following format:

```
{
    ...
    jsonPayload:{
                  'message': "{'message_type':'profile','runtime': 500}"                      
                }
 }
```

where instead of the jsonPayload being directly the sent dictionary, it is string encoded in 'message'. It's unclear what I should change in order to have the desired format on Stackdriver. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to format the logs you ingest into Stackdriver then you have to use Structured Logging.

If you use the Stackdriver Logging API or the command-line utility, gcloud logging, you can control the structure of your payloads. If you use the Stackdriver Logging agent to get your log entries, you can specify that the Logging agent convert your payloads to JSON format. See [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) for more information about different payload formats.

To enable structured logging, you must change the default configuration of the Logging agent when [installing or reinstalling](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#structured-log-install) it.

If your logs are not supported by the standard parsers, you can write your own. Parsers consist of a regular expression that is used to match log records and apply labels to the pieces. See some examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#writing_your_own_parser)